# strange behavior with spark

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I have a data fame like such

```
+-----------------------------------------+-----------------------+----------+---------------------------------------+
|id                                       |timestamp              |segment_id|centroid                               |
+-----------------------------------------+-----------------------+----------+---------------------------------------+
|01-9-0b18bb1e-eea1-4862-bb07-71fdde01b848|2022-03-12 15:21:53.529|null      |null                                   |
|01-9-0b18bb1e-eea1-4862-bb07-71fdde01b848|2022-03-12 15:21:54.528|null      |null                                   |
|01-9-0b18bb1e-eea1-4862-bb07-71fdde01b848|2022-03-12 15:21:55.527|null      |null                                   |
|01-9-0b18bb1e-eea1-4862-bb07-71fdde01b848|2022-03-12 15:21:56.527|null      |null                                   |
|01-9-0b18bb1e-eea1-4862-bb07-71fdde01b848|2022-03-12 15:21:57.526|null      |null                                   |
|01-9-0b18bb1e-eea1-4862-bb07-71fdde01b848|2022-03-12 15:21:58.525|null      |null                                   |
|01-9-0b18bb1e-eea1-4862-bb07-71fdde01b848|2022-03-12 15:21:59.525|null      |null                                   |
|01-9-0b18bb1e-eea1-4862-bb07-71fdde01b848|2022-03-12 15:22:00.524|null      |null                                   |
|01-9-0b18bb1e-eea1-4862-bb07-71fdde01b848|2022-03-12 15:22:01.524|null      |null                                   |
|01-9-0b18bb1e-eea1-4862-bb07-71fdde01b848|2022-03-12 15:22:02.523|null      |null                                   |
|01-9-0b18bb1e-eea1-4862-bb07-71fdde01b848|2022-03-12 15:22:03.523|null      |null                                   |
|01-9-0b18bb1e-eea1-4862-bb07-71fdde01b848|2022-03-12 15:22:04.522|366       |[42.52251447741435, -83.74453303719517]|
|01-9-0b18bb1e-eea1-4862-bb07-71fdde01b848|2022-03-12 15:22:05.522|null      |null                                   |
|01-9-0b18bb1e-eea1-4862-bb07-71fdde01b848|2022-03-12 15:22:06.522|null      |null                                   |
|01-9-0b18bb1e-eea1-4862-bb07-71fdde01b848|2022-03-12 15:22:07.521|null      |null                                   |
|01-9-0b18bb1e-eea1-4862-bb07-71fdde01b848|2022-03-12 15:22:08.521|null      |null                                   |
|01-9-0b18bb1e-eea1-4862-bb07-71fdde01b848|2022-03-12 15:22:09.520|null      |null                                   |
|01-9-0b18bb1e-eea1-4862-bb07-71fdde01b848|2022-03-12 15:22:10.519|null      |null                                   |
|01-9-0b18bb1e-eea1-4862-bb07-71fdde01b848|2022-03-12 15:22:11.520|null      |null                                   |
+-----------------------------------------+-----------------------+----------+---------------------------------------+
```

I am trying to filter it on a not null `segment_id` with the following code

```
df.where("segment_id is not null").show(truncate=False)
```

what results is the following correct row:

```
+-----------------------------------------+-----------------------+----------+--------+
|id                                       |timestamp              |segment_id|centroid|
+-----------------------------------------+-----------------------+----------+--------+
|01-9-0b18bb1e-eea1-4862-bb07-71fdde01b848|2022-03-12 15:22:04.522|null      |null    |
+-----------------------------------------+-----------------------+----------+--------+
```

So it seems like it picks the right row but somehow `segment_id` and centroid show up as null. The only time it works is if the not null value happens to be the first row of the dataframe.

Comment: Just for testing, can you try : `df.persist()`, `df.show()`,  `df.where("segment_id is not null").show(truncate=False)`. Does it change anything ?

Comment: Cn you check the dtype in relevant column, works for me `df= spark.createDataFrame([('01-9-0b18bb1e-eea1-4862-bb07-71fdde01b848','2022-03-12 15:22:03.523',None      ,None     )                             ,
('01-9-0b18bb1e-eea1-4862-bb07-71fdde01b848','2022-03-12 15:22:04.522',366       ,[42.52251447741435, -83.74453303719517])],
("id"  ,       "timestamp"        ,      "segment_id","centroid"     ))
df.show()` and  `df.where("segment_id is not null").show(truncate=False)`